# Memory Allocation In C , Use of Realloc

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

How do i use realloc function for calloc here. please guide ??
the first input of calloc function is giving me the right output but after using the realloc function my compiler just stuck , what mistake Am I doing here?
OUTPUT IS GIVEN:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n,n2,sum=0,i;
    int *ptr,*p;
    printf("Enter Totoal Number of elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ptr=(int*)calloc(n,sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter %d Element:",i+1);
        scanf("%d",ptr+i);
        sum=sum+*(ptr+i);
    }
    printf("The sum is: %d\n",sum);
    printf("Enter new size:");
    scanf("%d",&n2);
    p=(int *)realloc(ptr,n2*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
    sum=sum+*(p+i);
    printf("The new sum is:%d",sum);

    free(ptr);
    free(p);
}
```

[OUTPUT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdULP.png)

Comment: `sum=sum+*(p+i);` you have not initialized `p` to point to point somewhere. Undefined behaviour. Moreover, with `for(i=0;i<10*sizeof(int);i++)` you are trying to access memory which you do not own.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing that `realloc` with hardcoded size of `10` anyway. If your original `calloc` allocated memory was smaller than that, then the rest will be filled with rubbish and it's undefined behavior when you access it two lines later.

Comment: kinndly check question again i have updated it

Comment: The program probably crashes because you call `free` twice but you only malloc once. `p` and `ptr` point at the same memory.

Comment: please edit my code then

Answer (score 2):

Edit after update: you are double freeing the same pointer.

```
free(ptr);
free(p);
```

According to `man realloc`: realloc returns the pointer passed as argument, so `ptr` and `p` are the same. Actually you don't need two pointers here.

If you want to initialise go through `ptr` instead or `p`, which is what I guess you try to do then:

```
 for(i=0;i<10*sizeof(int);i++)
```

You are looping `10 * sizeof(int)` times to go through an array of size 10, accessing `*(ptr+i)` is like accessing `ptr[i]`, `ptr+i` evaluates to the address `ptr + sizeof(*p)`, you can read about pointer arithmetic if you want to learn more.

In your case, you are going out of bounds of your allocated memory, because your dynamically allocated array has size 10.

Comment: Slight correction: `Ptr` and `p` in `p=(int *)realloc(ptr,n2*sizeof(int))` are not necessarily the same, according to: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc

Answer (score 1):

You simply do not reset `sum` to zero.

```
printf("Enter new size:");
scanf("%d",&n2);
p=(int *)realloc(ptr,n2*sizeof(int));

for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
   sum=sum+*(p+i);

printf("The new sum is:%d",sum);
```

Before you ask for new size, you have already summed up the `n` entries.
Then you add on top of that the first `n2` entries.
If you want to cound only the `n2` entries, simply set `sum=0;` before you add up again.

Also You code will break if `n2 > n` as you do not provide new values for the new entries.

Another error:

```
free(ptr);
free(p);
```

You are not allowed to use `ptr` after you called `realloc`. It might have been free'd already in `realloc` if the memory location needed to be moved. Then that memory is not your's any more.
Or it might be same as `p`, then you will try to free the samem memory twice.
Both are no good ideas.